# Excel Service Application Error 5244 in Sharepoint 2010 Standard

Tags: excel-services, standard

We are seeing a lot of Excel Service Application errors in the Event logs, even though there is no Excel Service available in sharepoint 2010 standard that we are using.

1. How can I find out where this error is coming from?
2. Is there a way to suppress or hide these errors from appearing in Event Logs.?

Comment: are you trying to use the excel service's services...i.e open workbook etc

Comment: We use the Edit in Excel link to edit items, which takes us to Microsoft Excel. nothing else other than that.